# Is there website with list of common QA/QC errors?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, topology, data-quality

As I am working on reviewing my soils spatial data, and I am doing my QA/QC  I placed a point layer to check for errors.  I add the field column to mark the error and state the error.

I recently read the articles that came from ESRI on "Starting a Quality Assurance Program", "**[QA/AC for GIS Data: Initial Quality Control Checks](http://www.esri.com/news/podcasts/transcripts/qa_qcforgisdata_initialqualitycontrolchecks.pdf)**" and "QA/AC for GIS Data: Recording and Tracking Errors" transcripts.

Is there a website of where there are potential list of popular errors that I can take a look at or samples such as pictures of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this [post](http://www.gislounge.com/spatial-data-quality-an-introduction/) and [this one](http://www.gislounge.com/check-gis-data/).

Generally, our data should go through to two main Quality Assurance (QA) prisms:

1.Automatic – Checking rules that don’t require the human eye, and, oblige to preordained rules. All those rules you want your data to fit. For example, for the road layer, no dangles. Or buildings shouldn’t intersect roads unless the roads are tunnels.

2.Sampling – Checking a sample that would reflect the quality of the whole data, and requires human decipher. For example, let’s say you want to buy Point of Interest (POI) data that contain several types: culture, education and commerce. You’ll need to check a sample and see, with your own eyes and mind that the POIs are categorized correctly. How many should you check depends on the standard you use and the level of error you allow.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking for [Esri geodatabase topology rules poster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/001t/pdf/topology_rules_poster.pdf) which might be a good start. It shows possible errors and you could use this document as a reference.

There is also an extension called [ArcGIS Data Reviewer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_Data_Reviewer/01020000003p000000/) which was designed specifically for QA/QC jobs. It has a lot of functionality, but may be a bit hard to get started. There are a couple of tutorials available, too. If this would suit you well, consider an [Esri course](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?CourseID=50099063_9.X&fa=catalog.courseDetail).

Another helpful post here at [Automated quality control and assurance - geodata?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57243/automated-quality-control-and-assurance-geodata/57253#57253)