# Automated quality control and assurance - geodata?

Tags: data, data-quality

I've recently started looking at the issue of automated quality control and assurance of geographic data.

What software exists that can be used for accomplishing this? Esri has got their product 'Data Reviewer' which seems interesting, are there any comparable alternatives to this product?

I would like to tag this question with quality-control and quality-assurance, but can't do so.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. "geographic data" is a pretty broad topic for QA/QC, so perhaps you can explain what specific data you are dealing with, and what specific problems you need to overcome in that data?

Answer (score 4):

Quality control checking in GIS falls under two main categories, geometric and tabular.  Since GIS workflows are not standard your QA/QC process is unique to your case.

**Geometric**

In general most proprietary and open source GIS applications have a set of tools that check for geometric errors (e.g. ArcGIS [Checking and Repairing Geometries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000042000000), QGIS [Check Geometry Validity](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/2262), or GRASS [v.clean](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html)).

**Tabular**

Imputing tabular data workflow should start with creating domain within your database.  This will help prevent errors in attribution. For example in ArcGIS you can set up domains on geodatabase feature classes and tables ([Attribute Domain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000001000000)), in QGIS you can setup [attribute list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11960/how-to-have-a-drop-down-list-for-feature-editing-attributes-in-quantum-gis).

In both categories creating scripts or tools that are unique to your situation may also help check for both geometric and tabular errors.  I would recommend learning python which is utilized in both ArcGIS and QGIS.